# How identify these numbers from coinbase

Tags: python, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

My bot retrieves 'asks' and 'bids' from coinbase perfectly well, but there are random numbers also included with each result. These numbers are highlighted in the image below.

What do these numbers represent?

I know that the first number is the price of the bitcoin, and the second number is the amount for sale. What does this third number represent?

[image: asks and bids and ??? from coinbase]

The code works fine and is here

```
import cbpro

import time

public_client = cbpro.PublicClient()

while True:
  time.sleep(30)

  my_obj = public_client.get_product_order_book('BTC-USD', level=2)

  print('asks')
  print(my_obj['asks'][0])
  print(my_obj['asks'][1])
  print(my_obj['asks'][2])
  print(my_obj['asks'][3])
  print(my_obj['asks'][4])

  print('')

  print('bids')
  print(my_obj['bids'][0])
  print(my_obj['bids'][1])
  print(my_obj['bids'][2])
  print(my_obj['bids'][3])
  print(my_obj['bids'][4])
```

Comment: Have you seen [`get_product_order_book`](https://cbpro2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_client.html#cbpro.public_client.PublicClient.get_product_order_book)? Seems to imply it returns lists with *price, size, num-orders*

Comment: @JonClements do you mean that for the first ask on my image has 13 orders placed ready to sell/buy at that price? Thank you! :)

Comment: That's what the documentation says... not me!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([get_product_order_book](https://cbpro2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_client.html#cbpro.public_client.PublicClient.get_product_order_book)), this is the number of orders placed at that price.

For example, in the first 'ask' on my image, the first number circled in green has 13 orders placed ready to sell bitcoin at that price

Thanks to @JonClements for this answer